# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, slice, use-effect, metamask

Following a tutorial and I am stuck with this error.
I know the first part of the function will give me the first seven letters of my wallet address, and **currentAccount.slice(35)** will give from the 35th character onward.

The useEffect hook of `Header.js`

```
const Header = () => {
    const [selectedNav, setSelectedNav] = useState ('swap')
    const { connectWallet, currentAccount} = useContext(TransactionContext)
    const [ userName, setUserName] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setUserName( `${currentAccount.slice(0, 7)}...${currentAccount.slice(35)}`,)
    }, [currentAccount])


  console.log({connectWallet, currentAccount, })
```

The currentAccount function of `Header.js`, where *userName* was the previously hardcoded wallet address from the Header constant.

```
{currentAccount ? (
          <div className={`${style.button} ${style.buttonPadding}`}>
            <div className={style.buttonTextContainer}>{userName}</div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div
            onClick={() => connectWallet()}
            className={`${style.button} ${style.buttonPadding}`}
          >
            <div className={`${style.buttonAccent} ${style.buttonPadding}`}>
              Connect Wallet
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
```

In the following steps of the tutorial, the connected Metamask wallet address will be on display in the app.

**SOLVED** using the 'if' statement below

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(currentAccount)
      setUserName(`${currentAccount.slice(0, 7)}...${currentAccount.slice(35)}`,)
        }, [currentAccount])
```

Comment: It's telling you that `currentAccount` is `undefined`. Are you sure an object with that property name is being passed from the context? Are you rendering your `Header` component inside of a `TransactionContext.Provider`?